# JavaScript regex for a custom setting

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a JavaScript regular expression for the following example string:

```
caption:"My Test Caption" value:"My Test Value"
```

I'd like to have a regex that results in the following object or array:

```
object = {
  caption: "My Test Caption",
  value: "My Test Value"
}

array[0]="My Test Caption"
array[1]="My Test Value"
```

Comment: do you want to make these two string into array elements??

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: yes these 2 strings might be in a string of other characters, i want it to be captured into the array.

i tried /label\:(.*);|display\:\s*\w*|value\:(.*)/ig but it results in capturing the whole stretch into an array

array[0] = label:"something 1"; display:"something 2"; value:"something 3"

i don't want that. i want something like
array[0] = "something 1"
array[1] = "something 2"
array[2] = "something 3"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JJxtY/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question doesn't say anything about the allowed values for caption and value, I am assuming that caption can have any alphabet (minimum 1 alphabet)

```
var s = 'caption:"My Test Caption" value:"My Test Value"'
var r = /caption:"(.+)"\s+value:"(.+)"/
var a = s.match(r);
obj = {caption: a[1], value: a[2]}
```

Comment: Thank you, this very much helped solve my problem, but what if the string is not in order? How do i capture it then? such as s='value:"value" caption:"caption"

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to start with.

```
var myString = 'caption:"My Test Caption" value:"My Test Value"';
var myRegex = /caption:"(.*)" value:"(.*)"/g;
results = myRegex.exec(myString);

console.log(results[1])
console.log(results[2])
```

Here is another post on matching groups in javascript regex: [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regex)

Comment: I'm sorry your example doesn't work it still results in array[0] = caption:"My Test Caption" value:"My Test Value" it doesn't split the results into separate arrays

Comment: javascript's matcher puts the entire string in array[0], the split items will be in array[1], array[2] as I put above